# Javascript drop down menu widget

Tags: javascript, css, widget, prototypejs

I have a menu consisting of an <ul> in a Web CMS. 
I want several menu items to have sub-items that are displayed in a dropdown list. These sub-items are <ul>s as well.

This is basically easy to do with a few lines of CSS and Javascript, but I am looking for a ready-made Javascript solution that helps me handle the following:

- Deal with screen edge situations: If any part the dropdown menu would be outside the current viewport, place it so that it is completely within the viewport.

This is a bitch to code from scratch.

"Nice to have"s would be:

- Centered positioning below the drop-down button
- Adding a onclick event to the body so that clicking outside the drop down menu will close it; clean removal of the onclick event afterwards

But those I can do myself if necessary.

A nice, small, unobtrusive widget that magically converts my  <ul> would be lovely.

If the solution is based on a framework, it has to be Prototype as that's what I'm using in the CMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the offsets of the UL, and check whether those are in a certain distance of the viewport.

```
// Pseudo code
var ul = document.getElementById("menu");
if(ul.offset.x + ul.width > viewport.width) {
    ul.offset.x = viewport.width - ul.width;
}
```

It's also possible to get the exact position of the dropdown button clicked, and then you should apply basic math in order to position the menu beneath it.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. I know however from previous experience, that getting this right (taking into consideration scrollable containers, absolute / relative positioning and whatnot), and then making it work in all browsers, tends to eat up a lot of time. I would love to get around that :)

Comment: In that case a library would really help, unfortunately I cannot help you with those, because I tend to use my own libraries.